# php include expression prevents FullCalendar from rendering

Tags: javascript, php, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am dealing with 2 php files which are tabs.php and timetable.php. tabs.php acts as a navbar and directs the user to many pages including timetable.php. Whereas timetable.php has a FullCalendar that works perfectly. The way I direct the user from tabs.php to timetable.php is as follows:

```
<li><button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Timetable', this)"id="defaultOpen4">Timetable</button></li>
<div id="Timetable" class="tabcontent">
  <?php include("timetable.php"); ?>
</div>
```

The script for FullCalendar is as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: false, //Prevents user from moving around events
        header: {
          left: 'prev, next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
        },
        events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'loadEventsStudent.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {},
            success: function(data) {
              var events = [];

              for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                events.push({
                  title: data[i]['class'],
                  start: data[i]['start_event'],
                  end: data[i]['end_event'],
                });
              }
              //adding the callback
              callback(events);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

The issue is that when I go to the timetable page, only the buttons of the calendar are visible. Once I click any of these buttons, the calendar then gets rendered. The script for the FullCalendar works perfectly fine as I tried running it on another file which makes me think that the include expression is causing this issue. When I try to inspect the Network tab of my browser, I noticed that once I open the timetable page, nothing happens, but once I click on any of the calendars' buttons, the loadEventsStudent.php file (stores data from a database) appears and then the calendar gets rendered. Is there a way to make the calendar render without having to change the way both files are connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `include()` is a PHP function and the HTML code for your calendar is already loaded to the browser.

The quick fix I would suggest is to trigger a click on the calendar buttons when you are viewing the page, so it can load the calendar events when your are visiting the calendar tab.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   // Your code for the calendar comes here

   $("#defaultOpen4").on("click", function() {
     $( ".class-of-the-calendar-button" ).trigger( "click" );
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to add the line you suggested but it's giving me 3 errors. the first one is _".class-of-the-calendar-button"_ and it says "identifier expected". The second one is the '.' before the trigger and it says " '{' expected ". Lastly, the ; at the end which says " ',' expected ". I changed it to a ',' instead which seemed to get rid of this error. Kindly correct me if am wrong or if I am missing something

Comment: You have to replace the ``".class-of-the-calendar-button"`` with the actual class name of the calendar buttons. You can find the class name by right clicking on the button and selecting "Inspect Element".

Comment: You have to place the``$( ".class-of-the-calendar-button" ).trigger( "click" );`` at the bottom of your code.  Exactly before the last ``});`` in your JS code posted here.

Comment: It is not working and no errors are being generated in the console. The class I found following your steps was `$(".fc-today-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right fc-state-hover").trigger( "click" );`

Comment: Try ``$(".fc-today-button").trigger( "click" );``

Comment: Nope, doesn't work

Comment: I updated the answer to trigger the event on button click. This will work.

Comment: It is giving me an error after the word function. I tried to solve it and put () after it which made the line `$("#defaultOpen4").on("click", function(){` but it never fixed the calendar

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: this bracket after the word function '{' is underlined in red and it says " '(' expected ".

Comment: My bad.. There should be``()`` after function. I updated the code.